# Azure Durable Functions - Interface can't be instantiated! - Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, azure-durable-functions

While trying to build my first durable functions, I am getting this error. I didnt change default code from default file you get, when creating new durable function.

Part of the error:

```
{"name":"Cities","instanceId":"f0a50100-1556-4a82-ad2d- 
5b6d0f4eeed7","runtimeStatus":"Failed","input":null,"customStatus":null,"output": 
{"message":"Function 'Cities' failed with an unhandled 
exception.","details":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception 
while executing function: Functions.Cities\r\n ---> 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure\nException: 
UnsupportedOperationException: Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name: 
com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationContext\nStack: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable 
to create instance of interface com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationContext. 
Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a no-args constructor 
may fix this problem.\r\n\tat
```

As I am trying to run a default file.. I thing, meaby some library is missing? But I should have all prerequisites.

Host.json :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
        "hubName": "JavaTestHub"
    }
  },

  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.microsoft.azure.azurefunctions" version "1.12.0"
}
apply plugin: "java"

group 'com.phoenix.api'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.azure:azure-identity:1.9.0'

    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.functions:azure-functions-java-library:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.microsoft:durabletask-azure-functions:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.22.2'

    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.4.1.jre8'


    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20230227'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Is this resolved? Why is this error occurs in Intellij but not in VS Code?

Comment: It is not. That is good question, I was not able to make it work, so I just left Java and move on to C#. In my opinion it is better for Azure development as there is much more material, tutorials, etc. to go around.